# How to remove Ahnlab policy agent?

Tags: windows-7, security, uninstall

Anybody know how to remove the Ahnlab Policy agent? I was forced to install it so that I could connect to the campus network when I visited Korea. Now that I'm home, I would like to remove it. However, it resists all uninstallation efforts. It gives me an

> Access is denied

error whenever I try to stop the service. Here's what I tried so far:

- AppRemover. Doesn't work.
- Uninstall in safe mode. Doesn't work
  either.

Does anybody know of a solution short of booting up a Linux distro and deleting the Ahnlab files with it?